# Pandas: Add Datetime as prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to add the date as a prefix to the column names to get something like this:

```
In: 
Source

Out:
DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-13 10:00:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='timestamp', freq=None)

In:
table = ['AR']
table = table.add_prefix(source[0][0]+'_')

Out:
2020-10-13 10:00:00+00:00_AR
```

However I am getting te following error:

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'
**

I am not sure how to fix this. Also, is it possible to remove the UTC time? i.e. remove the "+00:00"

Comment: `list(map(lambda x:f"{x.tz_localize(None)}+00:00_AR",Source))`?

Comment: `table = str(source[0]) + '_' + table[0]` ?

Comment: `table.add_prefix( source[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_')` should do the trick, you need to convert the object to a string first. `source[0][0]` throws an error for me.. `TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Thanks all! @Umar.H's suggestion worked best